# New update to Search Console? - missing Desktop render

Tags: google-search-console, url-inspection-tool

So as some might noticed on January 9th Google updated their algorithms
Source: https://www.semrush.com/sensor/?category=&db=US&date=2019-01-09

But today I found out that if I do URL inspection in New Search Console, the Screenshot is Mobile version of site (it usually was Desktop), but then there is still option to see Mobile friendly website, and if I check the screenshot for mobile there, it is indeed mobile version of page - the same as [incorect] Desktop.

What, Who, Why? What is happening? Does Desktop version is completely wiped off? Is desktop version of website now useless?